# Run a program on server-side via web

Tags: php, html, server-side

I just bought a raspberry and I want to order many actions in their side to do from a menu web page.

So, I want to do something like shutdown the machine or execute programs inside the raspberry without a remote desktop. So, I want that, a web menu where I can manage all this commands.

I only want many commands can execute server-side programs.
I was learning php and I know it may work but when I try to execute programs with exec(), a shell appears its cannot find the file.

Example:

```
<?php 
   exec('cd C:\users\Monkey\Desktop');
   exec('START games.txt');
?>
```

Exit:

A error message from cmd:

> Windows cannot find the file "games.txt". Be sure you wrote it properly and try later.

Comment: you need to provide some of your code so we can help you better. look into `exec` http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @user1844933 hes talking about a `raspberry pi`

Comment: `cd` in an `exec` call won't work like that. Use [`chdir`](http://php.net/chdir) instead, or specify the full path for `games.txt`. For launching apps on Windows, though, you probably want http://php.net/com instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you to everyone, I tried to put full path for the archive and it works. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php exec('START C:\users\Monkey\Desktop\games.txt'); ?>
```

Thank you to everyone who helped me :D